# How to integrate this equation in Matlab

Tags: integration

How to integrate this equation in Matlab
$f(x)=\int_0^L \cos[m(x+l)]\cosh[m(x-l)] \sin(\pi x/l) \; dx $
 I want to integrate from $0$ to $L$.
This is my code in Matlab, but unfortunately I did not get any result;

$ syms $         $ x~ l~ m~ pi~ $

$f=\cos[m*(x+l)]* \cosh[m*(x-l)]* \sin(pi* x/l);$

$S=int(f,0,l)$

Comment: Your function might not have an analytical solution. Have a look at numerical approaches, like ode45 or ode15s.

Comment: I look at ode45 but I did not fin any similar example to my question. Could anyone give me hint please.

Comment: If you are to use ode functions you will have to reduce to one variable btw. Otherwise there are pde functions you could try, but these have restrictions as well. What specifically do you have a problem with?

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas for your suggestion, I tried to integrate the above function using ode45,  I set $x0=0,1;$  $tspan=[0:0.1:1]$ where $L=1$ Then  [t,x]=ode45(@Myfunction,tspan,x0); Is that correct or not?

Comment: In Mathematica `FullSimplify[Integrate[Cos[m (x + l)] Cosh[m (x - l)] Sin[Pi x/l], {x, 0, L}]]` gives an answer (it's a fairly large expression).

Comment: What `version` of Matlab are you using? This works fine in R2015a. Note that it makes no sense to define `pi` in your `syms` line (you might use `sym('pi')` in your equation though) and square brackets aren't used for functions in Matlab.